How to View Windchill .pvz Files Directly in Mendix Using REST APIs?
I’m working on a Mendix application where my customer needs to view Windchill .pvz files (3D CAD files) directly within the application before downloading them. The files are being fetched from a REST API with basic authentication.
If anyone has experience with a similar use case, I’d appreciate insights or references to suitable solutions.
What I’ve Tried

Fetching .pvz Files: Successfully retrieved the .pvz files using REST APIs in Mendix.
Viewing .pvz Files: Tried rendering the files in a viewer within Mendix, but no success so far.
External Tools: Explored using CreoView and other CAD viewers, but they often require launching a separate application.

Expecting:

The solution should allow users to view .pvz files directly within Mendix without needing to download or open them in external applications.
The viewer must support 3D CAD formats like .pvz.

Thank you in advance for your help!
